# Is there a strong cryptographic reason for GCM's 2^39 - 256 bit limit?

Tags: gcm

In reading through the original GCM specification ([McGrew & Viega '05](http://www.mindspring.com/~dmcgrew/gcm-nist-6.pdf)), the composition of the 128 bit Initialization Vector as a concatenation of a 96b nonce and a 32b unsigned wrapping counter seems arbitrary and forces the scrambling pattern to repeat every 2<sup>32</sup> 16-byte block.

Is the algorithm expected to be secure for significantly longer stream lengths if for example the IV were a 128b nonce XORed with a 64b or 128b counter, or are there known cryptanalysis issues that begin to arise?

Comment: In practice, the counter will not wrap, as that many blocks is 64GB. Additionally, an implementation should increment the nonce upon rolling the counter, and/or throw an error. The limit is related to the authentication component of GCM when used with a 96-bit authentication value, not CTR mode.

Comment: @Jeff do you have any use case where this limit is an issue ?

Answer (score 1):

In the same document the authors in section 2.1 specifies the plaintext size to be between $0$ and $2^{39}-256$ bits = $2^{36}-32$ bytes = $2^{32}-2$ blocks of 16 bytes.

That's the rationale behind the choice of the counter size. Given that requirement it will never overlap/wrap, which means you will never end up having repeating the "scrambling pattern" for the same message.

This constrains the maximum message size to $2^{36}-32 = 68.719.476.704 B$ approximately 64GB which didn't seem a problem to the authors.

Now, this choice of the counter constrains also the number of messages that can be protected under the same key at $2^{(128-32)=96}$ since the nonce is made by 96 bits.

If you look at section 3.1 of [this paper](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/comments/CWC-GCM/gcm-update.pdf) by the GCM's original authors they gave the rationale above for their choices commenting that "any mode built upon a counter mode will have a similar tradeoff" {between maximum message size and number of messages under the same key}.

Now, you can easily modify GCM, by increasing the counter to 64 bits and decreasing the nonce to 64 bits and still have a secure authenticated encryption mode.
AES-CCM, for example, by specification support messages up to $2^{64}-1$ bytes.